# Why i can't render results with the webpage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express

I'm using Express with SQLite and SQLite3 modules. When I run the server, data doesn't show up in the first request. I have to refresh in order for the data to appear.

The best solution I've tried is to make `db.each()`, which I'm using to fetch the data, return an appointment so I can wait for the promise before the page renders, but that didn't work.

I've checked a lot of documentation and tutorials but I couldn't find the solution I need. I've read a tutorial that uses SQLite3-express but I only want to use SQLite3

prog.js file

```
const db = require('./db');
const config = require('../config');

async function getMultiple() {
  await db.query("SELECT id, name FROM users")
}

module.exports = {
  getMultiple
}
```

db.js file

```
const mysql = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const path = ("C:/Users/Administrateur.DESKTOP-OQRUHSR/Desktop/sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3410000/db/test.db")
let rows = ["i suck"]

function query(sql) {
  let db = new mysql.Database(path, (err) => {
    if (err) { console.log("error") }
    else { console.log("success") }
  })

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.each(sql, (err, row) => {
      if (err) { console.error(err.message) }
      else { rows.push(row) ? console.log(row.id, row.name) : console.log("not found") }
    })
    resolve(rows)
  })
}

module.exports = {
  query
}
```

routes.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const programmingLanguages = require('../services/prog');

/* GET programming languages. */
router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    res.json(await programmingLanguages.getMultiple());
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error while getting programming languages `, err.message);
    next(err);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Typo?  The `getMultiple()` function never returns a value.

Comment: @David it doesn't need to since routes file calls the getMultiple function which in turn calls the query function in the db.js file, else how would the results get rendered in the second refresh?

Comment: How/where do these results "get rendered"?  It seems misleading that you're returning this result as JSON if you're aware that there is no result to return: `res.json(await programmingLanguages.getMultiple());`

Comment: @David the index.js file uses the routes.js file, that's where the results get rendered, however i can't understand why the results don't get rendered at first request, the data are being returned

Comment: The results "get rendered" *in a js file*?  It's not clear to me what you mean by that.  The code shown logs data to the Node console.  But the question title mentions a web page.  If you're [already aware that this route doesn't *return* anything to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75732646/why-i-cant-render-results-with-the-webpage?noredirect=1#comment133599045_75732646), is that web page even involved or relevant? Are you just observing the Node console and nothing else? What specific observations are you making on the Node console and how do they differ from what you expect?

Comment: The logic in the `query()` function also seems suspect.  Is `db.each()` synchronous or asynchronous?  If it's issuing a query to a database then I would expect the latter.  But the code shown is expecting the former, because `resolve(rows)` is called immediately afterward.

Comment: it an asyncronous function, because of the db.each() but it doesn't return any promise hence i can't use async-await on it, i made the query function return a promise so that i can wait for the fetch to end before rendering the page, sadly it doesn't, as you can see routes file is waiting for the promise

Comment: @David sorry i meant index.html file

Comment: @David the routes does show the results as when i visit the link i get the results after second refresh

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
db.each(sql, (err, row) => {
  if (err) { console.error(err.message) }
  else { rows.push(row) ? console.log(row.id, row.name) : console.log("not found") }
})
resolve(rows)
```

`db.each()` is *asynchronous*.  Which means the order of operations here is as follows:

1. Invoke `db.each()` and queue the callback.
2. *Immediately return* `rows`.
3. When the database query finishes, push results to `rows` and log those results to the console.

If you want all of the rows at once, use `db.all` instead.  For example:

```
db.all(sql, [], (err, results) => {
  if (err) { console.error(err.message) }
  else {
    results.forEach((row) => {
      rows.push(row) ? console.log(row.id, row.name) : console.log("not found")
    });
    resolve(rows);
  }
});
```

---

Note that there very well could be a wide variety of other problems in the code.  Including, but not limited to:

1. If `rows` is in global or module scope, multiple requests may be pushing the same results to the same array multiple times.
2. Your manually created `Promise` never *rejects*, so you may have a hanging unresolved `Promise` if there's ever an error.
3. `getMultiple()` doesn't return anything.  (More specifically, it returns an awaitable `Promise` which doesn't *resolve to* anything.)

Overall there appears to be a lot of confusion in this code between what is synchronous and what is asynchronous, and a lot of confusion over where/how you expect results to be returned or rendered.  So even when you correct the issue of `query()` returning a `Promise` which immediately resolves without waiting for the database results, that is no guarantee that your entire end-to-end functionality will "work", given that it's not entirely clear what you even expect "work" to mean in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you need a return in your getMultiple() function, because the function doesn't return anything.

```
async function getMultiple() {
return await db.query("SELECT id, name FROM users")
}
```